# Fourier transform of a piecewise continuous function

Tags: fourier-transform

$$
 f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & x<3 \\
x, & 3\le x\le 5\\
0, & x>5
\end{cases}
$$

---

$=\int^5_3 x e^{-1\xi x}$ $dx$

$=-\frac{x}{i \xi} + \int \frac{e^{-1\xi x}}{i \xi}$ $dx$

$=-\frac{x}{i \xi}+\frac{e^{-1\xi x}}{\xi^2}|^5_3$

$=e^{-5i\xi}(\frac{1}{\xi^2}-\frac{5}{i\xi})+e^{-3i\xi}(\frac{3}{i\xi}-\frac{1}{\xi^2})$

But the answer is

$=(5i\xi^{-1}+\xi^{-2})e^{-5i\xi}-(3i\xi^{-1}+\xi^{-2})e^{-3i\xi}$

Comment: Check your computations, the answer is correct...

Comment: So what is your question? These two things are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same solution but there is difference between your solution and the answer in terms of notation

- The imaginary unit is the numerator in the given answer
- The fractions are written as negative powers in the given answer